# How to grep on a column? (vertical scan instead of horizontal scan)

Tags: awk, grep

Lets say I have a series of values in no particular order:

```
Metric1 Metric3 Metric4 Metric5  Metric9  Metric8
Value1  Value3  Value4  Value5  Value9  Value8
```

What is the best way to grep for Metric5 and spit out that column?

For instance

```
grep Metric5 <file>
```

Should return

```
Metric5
Value5
```

EDIT: In retrospect this is where Python Pandas and csvcut seems to be a lot more efficient.

Python Route:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header = None)
df[['metric5', 'metric5']]
```

csvcut:

data

```
$ cat test-cols.dat 
id  name  age
1   ed    50
2   joe   70
```

command:

```
$ cat test-cols.dat | tr -s ' ' ',' | csvcut -c id,age | tr ',' ' ' | column -t
id  age
1   50
2   70
```

Comment: What should `grep Value3 <file>`return?

Answer (score 3):

In general:

```
awk -v colNames="Metric5 Metric1 Metric9" '
BEGIN { split(colNames,tmp); for (i in tmp) tgts[tmp[i]] }
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i in tgts) {
            fldNrs[++numTgts] = i
        }
    }
}
{
    for (tgtNr=1; tgtNr<=numTgts; tgtNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", $(fldNrs[tgtNr]), (tgtNr<numTgts ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
' file
Metric1 Metric5 Metric9
Value1 Value5 Value9
```

If you just want 1 column selected then obviously just list 1 on the `-v` assignment

Comment: Oh wow, didn't even think of multiple matches. Then again, `foo` was pretty strong in my solution anyway, `it` seems.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat > foo.awk
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        a[i][NR]=$i
        if(foo==$i) 
            it=i
} nr=NR
} END {
    if(it!="") 
        for(i=1;i<=nr;i++) 
            print a[it][i]
}
$ awk -v foo="Metric5" -f foo.awk foo
Metric5
Value5
```